# How to update bootstrap (tooltip) of a moving object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a moving `<div>` object. I want to show/update this `tooltip info`, let say every `2s`. It works fine but the position doesn't change even if the object had moved, the `tooltip` keeps the initial position and stay static (sorry i didn't provide a working example).

How can I update its position to follow the `<div>` (not the mouse) ?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle? I know that in other tooltip libraries, you can set options for it to display where you click or position it relative to your container

Answer (score 0):

## event.pageX and event.pageY

The description below is for event.pageX
Description: The mouse position relative to the left edge of the document.

Below is the code i had used in one of my application.

You can show the div below on a mouseover event.

```
date.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {
        return d.mattel_data;
    })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y1);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1);
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
    })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        div.transition()
            .duration(100)
            .style("opacity", .9);
            var hoverVal = (d.y1 - d.y0);
            var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US',{
              style : 'currency',
              currency : 'USD',
              minimumFractionDigits : 2,
            });
            var pop = formatter.format(hoverVal);
            // console.log(pop);
            div.html("Value:" + pop + "<br/>" + d.name)
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 140) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 80) + "px")
            .style('position', 'absolute')
            .style('font-size', '15px')
            .style('background', function() {
                return color(d.name);
            })
            .style('color', function() {
                return getContrastYIQ(color(d.name));
            })
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        div.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", 0);
    });
```

See if that helps you out.
Also if you post your code here that will help to understand your problem more clearly